# How to properly apply onPreferenceChangeListener?

Tags: android

In the [Udacity Android development video](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud853/l-1474559101/e-1643578589/m-1643578588) on Modifying SettingsActivity, I implemented the code as per [this gist](https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/blob/5204747e9378f65bf4a474da4b5c08f61a64d37c/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/app/SettingsActivity.java) but am getting an error on Android Monitor saying

> 03-18 10:52:59.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2520): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.sunshine/com.example.android.sunshine.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.preference.Preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(android.preference.Preference$OnPreferenceChangeListener)' on a null object reference

The relevant code is

```
   private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
}
```

So it looks like `this` is undefined, is that right?

Answer (score 5):

The `preference` being passed is null in this case.
The real culprit could be the **missing entry in the XML layout** file that you code references.

Easy way to find that out is look at the stack trace and see which field it is being called for, from your `SettingsActivity` or some Activity where it is being referenced.
For example:

```
bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("mytypes"));
```

See if that `enabled` in the case above is being added to your layout like this:

```
<ListPreference
   android:entries="@array/pref_my_types"
   android:entryValues="@array/pref_my_values"
   android:key="mytypes"
   android:title="MyTypes"/>
```

If this is missing, it will throw a `NPE` and `findPreference("mytypes")` would return null.

Answer (score 0):

Think its more likely that your Preference object is null.  In this instance, 'this' is referring to the Activity that is running bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference), so it can't be null.  Set a break point to the line:

```
preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

and you will be able to see for certain which is null when you run debug.

Answer (score 0):

The key in the EditTextPreference should match the key in bindPreferenceSummaryToValue.

```
   <EditTextPreference
       android:key="@string/pref_location_key"
       android:title="@string/pref_location_label"
       android:defaultValue="@string/pref_default_display_name"
       android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
       android:inputType="textCapWords"
       android:capitalize="words"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:maxLines="1" />
```

and the key which i passed in `bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key)));`
Android:key value and  bindPreferenceSummaryToValue should point to same.